# creating regions for Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How Can I create regions for a user defined language in NotePad++?
I found that in View->User Defined Language menu, we can type keywords that I want it to use for region open and closing so I typed "if"  and "endif" , worked..but the problem is that I cannot type more! I want "for" and "endfor" for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the user defined language feature, spaces are used to separate keywords. In your example, the **Folder Open Keywords Settings** would contain:

```
if for
```

and the **Folder Close Keywords Settings** would contain:

```
endif endfor
```